# Change the displayed text on same page of a <td> or <input> element after some action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

I have searched for this answer and it seems that it should be simple, based on DOM.
What I want to do is display a `<td id="cte">` or `<input id="cte">` on a page and after some action (i.e. button click OR onchange ) the `getElementById('cte').value="somenewvalue"` ACTUALLY changes the forementioned  or  element on the same page.

The technology (i.e. javascript, AJAX, DOM) says that this is doable, yet I have seen this question asked numerous ways where the answers supplied never seem to work or satisfy the question.

**So my actual question is:  How do I change the 'displayed' element.value on the same page without having to reload the same page?**

Comment: Show us what you have try with a snipet. [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Do you think of elements consist several values/texts? (like a table)

//emty the element really at first if the element consists several values

```
var forempty = document.getElementById("cte");

while( forempty.firstChild ){
        forempty.removeChild(forempty.firstChild);
    }
document.getElementById("cte").value = something;
//or 
document.getElementById("cte").textContent = something;
```

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question at least in one way: "***The technology (i.e. javascript, AJAX, DOM) says that this is doable.*** And sure enough, with AJAX, it is only a matter of replacing the DOM Node with the Data (Response) from AJAX Request...

Here is a very Basic Example. We will fetch an HTML String using AJAX from the Server and use this Contents to replace the former Contents of a DIV, which contains the HTML `< strong>Hello< /strong>`

The first part of this Demo is our HTML or PHP Document containing our initial Markup and this File, we'd call `index.html or index.php`

> **CONTENTS OF index.php | index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mini AJAX Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="swappable-content" id="swappable-content">
    <strong>Hello!!!</strong>
</div>
<div class="other-dom-elements">
    <Button id="action-trigger" data-ajax-url="/ajax.php">Click Me</Button>
</div>
<!-- ADD JQUERY LIBRARY & SETUP THE AJAX REQUEST CALLS -->
<!-- HERE WE ARE LOADING JQUERY FROM THE CDN.... CHANGE THE src ATTRIBUTE IF YOU HAVE A LOCAL COPY -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(e){
      var actionTrigger   = $("#action-trigger");

      actionTrigger.on("click", function(e){
        $.ajax({
          url         : $(this).attr('data-ajax-url'),
          type        : "POST",
          dataType    : "JSON",
          data        : {
            // HERE YOU CAN ADD KEY VALUE PAIRS
            // WHICH WILL BE SENT TO AND PROCESSED BY THE SERVER
          },
          success     : successHandler,
          error       : errorHandler,
          complete    : completeHandler

        });
      });

      function successHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // IF THERE IS A RESPONSE PAYLOAD FROM THE SERVER
        // WE JUST REPLACE THE CONTENTS OF THE #swappable-content DIV WITH THE DATA
        if(data){
          if(data.html){
            $("#swappable-content").html(data.html);
          }
        }
      }

      function errorHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log('The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
      }

      function completeHandler(jqXHR, textStatus){

      }
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> **CONTENTS OF AJAX PROCESSING SCRIPT: ajax.php**

```
<?php

    // YOU CAN DO PRETTY MUCH ANYTHING WITHIN THIS FILE
    // HOWEVER FOR THE PURPOSES OF THIS DEMO,
    // WE WOULD JUST RETURN SOME HTML STRING BUNDLED IN AN ARRAY AND SENT AS JSON DATA
    $response   = array(
        'html'  => "<div style='font-weight:900;color:#F00;'>This is the Response Data from Server!</div>",
    );

    die(json_encode($response));
```